# Scrollable Data Tables using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create a vue page that has two data-tables that fill half the screen (vertically). Each data table should have a scroll bar if required.

I have tried the markup below, but this does not size the data-tables to the screen size. Here is a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/douglasjwoods/pen/gdqRPX)

```html
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-md fill-height>
      <v-layout column>
        <v-flex md6>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="desserts"
            hide-actions
            class="elevation-1"
          >
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
          </v-flex>
        <v-flex md6>
          <div>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="desserts"
            hide-actions
            class="elevation-1"
          >
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
              <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
          </div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess it will be results you expect if you remove `fluid` prop from `v-container`.

Comment: Is this what you need? https://codepen.io/Lawrence_Nara/pen/NLoBgL. I believe it is also possible to use a computed property with style and change the max-height per viewport

Comment: Removing the fluid does not give the required result. @kuromoka

Comment: @nara_l, adding a max-height style does get close, but I want the flex to automatically calculate the height. I have set both tables to md6, so I expect them to each take half the available height

Comment: how will we fixed header of table when it is able to scorll

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To acheive the result I needed to set the height to 100vh on the layout, and set overflow on each flex. I have updated the codepen in question

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
 <v-container>
  <v-layout column style="height: 90vh">       <--- added height
    <v-flex md6 style="overflow: auto">        <--- added overflow
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      </v-flex>
    <v-flex md6 style="overflow: auto">        <--- added overflow
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
 </v-container>
</v-app>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. For anyone else who would like to see this in action, I created a [CodePen based on Douglas' answer](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPXZaX).

Comment: Can we do it without setting up the `style="height: 90vh"`. I would like to set the number of records to display per view and a scroll to view the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 7):

In Vuetify 2 it simply a matter of setting the `height` and `fixed-header` props. Not in the docs or examples, but found it over in the simple-table examples.

Comment: it will show scroll on whole table. but it should be visible only on body part

Answer (score 2):

Even though it has already been answered.
I see that the answer above is not spelled correctly.
Below is the correct example code for this.

```
<v-responsive
         class="overflow-y-auto"
          max-height="calc(90vh - 520px)">
</v-responsive
```

Or

```
</v-data-table
>
    <template v-slot:body>
         <v-responsive
               class="overflow-y-auto"
               max-height="calc(90vh - 520px)"
          >
                <tbody>
                      <tr>
                           <td>example</td>
                           <td><strong>test example</strong></td>
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
         </v-responsive>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: If we set the `body` slot, sorting no longer works after this. The docs say: > It is important to note some slot (eg: item/body/header) will completely takes over the internal rendering of the component which will require you to re-implement functionalities such as selection and expansion.